# Aggregating a large pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that lists SystemIDs and the number of alarms of certain types and class which happened on certain dates:

```
df
                               SystemID         AlarmClass          AlarmType         Day  AlarmCount
0  95EE8B57-6BE9-4175-B901-B6B3BEE1844D            Service  Unexpected Status  06/08/2018           3
1  95EE8B57-6BE9-4175-B901-B6B3BEE1844D            Service  Unexpected Status  05/08/2018           2
2  95EE8B57-6BE9-4175-B901-B6B3BEE1844D            Service  Unexpected Status  06/08/2018           1
3  5F891F03-3114-4E62-9A7D-CD2A04061364            Service  Unexpected Status  04/08/2018           2
4  5F891F03-3114-4E62-9A7D-CD2A04061364            Service  Unexpected Status  04/08/2018           2
5  5F891F03-3114-4E62-9A7D-CD2A04061364  Event Log Monitor    Application Log  05/08/2018           2
```

I would like to aggregate this data by grouping on SystemID and Day and listing the number of alarms of each type and class. The result for the above dataframe would look like this:

```
                               SystemID         Day  AlarmClass-S  AlarmClass-ELM  AlarmType-US  AlarmType-AL
0  95EE8B57-6BE9-4175-B901-B6B3BEE1844D  06/08/2018             4               0             4             0
1  95EE8B57-6BE9-4175-B901-B6B3BEE1844D  05/08/2018             2               0             2             0
2  5F891F03-3114-4E62-9A7D-CD2A04061364  04/08/2018             4               0             4             0
3  5F891F03-3114-4E62-9A7D-CD2A04061364  05/08/2018             0               2             0             2
```

How to do this most efficiently? The dataframe has millions of records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For performance, you can pivot your data for each of AlarmClass and AlarmType then and concatenate the results.

```
i = df.pivot_table(index=['SystemID', 'Day'], 
                   columns='AlarmClass', 
                   values='AlarmCount', 
                   aggfunc='sum', 
                   fill_value=0)
j = df.pivot_table(index=['SystemID', 'Day'], 
                   columns='AlarmType', 
                   values='AlarmCount', 
                   aggfunc='sum', 
                   fill_value=0)

i.columns = i.columns.map(lambda x: 'AlarmClass-' + ''.join(y[0] for y in x.split()))
j.columns = j.columns.map(lambda x: 'AlarmType-' + ''.join(y[0] for y in x.split()))

df = pd.concat([i, j], axis=1).reset_index()
```

```
print(df)
                               SystemID         Day  AlarmClass-ELM   \
0  5F891F03-3114-4E62-9A7D-CD2A04061364  04/08/2018               0             
1  5F891F03-3114-4E62-9A7D-CD2A04061364  05/08/2018               2             
2  95EE8B57-6BE9-4175-B901-B6B3BEE1844D  05/08/2018               0             
3  95EE8B57-6BE9-4175-B901-B6B3BEE1844D  06/08/2018               0             

AlarmClass-S  AlarmType-AL  AlarmType-US
           4             0             4
           0             2             0
           2             0             2
           4             0             4
```